# MySQL Selecting information

Tags: mysql, database

So I need help with searching for some information. I am searching for rooms where there are free space in room. I added picture of tables how it looks like before and after. I hope thats enough information :) [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select r.door_nr, 
       r.space - sum(p.name is not null) as free
from rooms r
left join people p on p.door_nr = r.door_nr
group by r.door_nr, r.space
having free > 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dbfb/2)

Comment: Ok, it helps, but maybe You know how to disable rows with 0 in column Free_space

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding out how many people are in each room:

```
SELECT door_nr
     , Count(*) As number_of_occupants
FROM   people
GROUP
    BY door_nr
```

Then we can use this query and join it back to the `rooms` table based on matching `door_nr` values.

```
SELECT rooms.door_nr
     , rooms.space As capacity
     , room_usage.number_of_occupants
     , rooms.space - room_usage.number_of_occupants As free_space
FROM   rooms
 LEFT
  JOIN (
        SELECT door_nr
             , Count(*) As number_of_occupants
        FROM   people
        GROUP
            BY door_nr
       ) As room_usage
    ON room_usage.door_nr = rooms.door_nr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Door_Nr, COUNT(*) FROM People GROUP BY Door_Nr
```

will give you the number of people in the room.

With a basic working knowledge of (My)SQL, you should be able to figure out the rest?
Otherwise, please ask a specific question.